# Laravel Cashier stripe webhook response failed but everything works

Tags: php, laravel, stripe-payments, webhooks, laravel-cashier

So I do not understand fully what is happening but I suspect I am missing something silly.

I am creating a subscription in stripe via cahier with the usage of the stripe hosted checkout page. This is all in testing and not live.

Now when I click subscribe button I go to checkout and I create new sub and go back to my system. That is all great. I see sub in my database and I see new sub on stripe.

I see in local stripe CLI something like this

```
2022-12-08 11:19:45  --> setup_intent.succeeded [evt_1MCi8jEgkYGsrIK1noJjDJzl]
2022-12-08 11:19:45  --> setup_intent.created [evt_1MCi8jEgkYGsrIK1IaP2tuw9]
2022-12-08 11:19:45 <-- [200] POST http://contract.test/stripe/webhook [evt_1MCi8jEgkYGsrIK1noJjDJzl]
2022-12-08 11:19:45 <-- [200] POST http://contract.test/stripe/webhook [evt_1MCi8jEgkYGsrIK1IaP2tuw9]
2022-12-08 11:19:46  --> checkout.session.completed [evt_1MCi8kEgkYGsrIK1e8rGl5KO]
2022-12-08 11:19:46 <-- [200] POST http://contract.test/stripe/webhook [evt_1MCi8kEgkYGsrIK1e8rGl5KO]
2022-12-08 11:19:46  --> invoice.created [evt_1MCi8kEgkYGsrIK1v2x9UsFC]
2022-12-08 11:19:46 <-- [200] POST http://contract.test/stripe/webhook [evt_1MCi8kEgkYGsrIK1v2x9UsFC]
2022-12-08 11:19:46  --> invoice.finalized [evt_1MCi8kEgkYGsrIK12Gc2WKwy]
2022-12-08 11:19:46 <-- [200] POST http://contract.test/stripe/webhook [evt_1MCi8kEgkYGsrIK12Gc2WKwy]
2022-12-08 11:19:46  --> invoice.paid [evt_1MCi8kEgkYGsrIK1zBrQaMLG]
2022-12-08 11:19:46 <-- [200] POST http://contract.test/stripe/webhook [evt_1MCi8kEgkYGsrIK1zBrQaMLG]
2022-12-08 11:19:46  --> invoice.payment_succeeded [evt_1MCi8kEgkYGsrIK1iovWPu3A]
2022-12-08 11:19:47 <-- [200] POST http://contract.test/stripe/webhook [evt_1MCi8kEgkYGsrIK1iovWPu3A]
2022-12-08 11:19:47  --> customer.subscription.created [evt_1MCi8kEgkYGsrIK1gBbRRIWs]
2022-12-08 11:19:47 <-- [200] POST http://contract.test/stripe/webhook [evt_1MCi8kEgkYGsrIK1gBbRRIWs]
```

In my .env as a webhook key I've put the one that stripe client gives me when I start it.

In my stripe dashboard I can see some problems though each and every webhook call gives me `Failed to connect to remote host`
Is that something to do with testing setup or it supposed to be like that when I am using CLI or did I do something wrong?

I have Laravel 9 , vue3 and I followed just regular instructions for cashier.

Comment: contract.test is not a public domain, it' impossible for an external service like Stripe to connect to that domain and send a request, hence the error. It works if you use Stripe CLI since it's able to forward events across your local network

Comment: Hey @karllekko that is what I was initially thinking but I was convinced that because I am listening locally Stripe will sort of figure that out. So I can assume that is just ok and then perhaps test it when I put it on like staging server I should be able to see these events coming through?

Comment: I would say so, if you configure the webhook endpoint in the Stripe settings to use a public URL it should work.

Comment: @karllekko nice one I will then leave it be for now and do final testing on staging server when the time comes.